# Is there a way to add and start a .Net Core 2.0 REST server inside a .Net Framework 4.5.2 (or .Net Framework 4.6.1 or .Net Standard 2.0) application?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

## Issue

Hi,
I am currently working on implementing a RESTful API in C# using ASP.net Core 2.0 in Visual Studio 2017 (running only via Kestrel, therefore no IIS).

Everything works pretty well, no issues there. The thing is that I now need to integrate and start this REST Server in another project (The REST server being only one of many functionalities that need to be executed at the same time, using a "bootstrap"). My issue here is that the latter project targets .Net Framework 4.5.2 whereas the REST server targets .Net Core 2.0. Thus, when I add the REST server to the references of my bootstrap application, I encounter a couple of errors saying that some of the Nuget packages target the wrong framework.

## Solutions I tried

I searched over Google but most of the issues I found were people trying to do the other way round, i.e. adding a .Net Framework-targeted project in a .Net Core application.

The way I understood this [.Net implementation support table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support), is that a .Net standard 2.0 project can support a .Net Core 2.0 project (I am probably wrong).
I tried a couple of things to make it work (which, spoiler alert, obviously and unfortunately did not work as I wouldn't be asking your help) :

- Made the boostrap application target .Net Standard 2.0
- Made the boostrap application target .Net Framework 4.6.1
- Made the REST server application target .Net Standard 2.0 (which it of course didn't work, but I was kind of desperate..)

I made these target change by modifying the .csproj files.

I don't have the exact error codes because I reverted my changes a while back but they all were about projects not targeting the same framework.

So, in a tl;dr manner, what I am asking is :

#### Is there a way to add a .net Core 2.0 REST server inside a .Net Framework 4.5.2 (or 4.6.1 and higher/ or .Net Standard 2.0) project to start the server inside the application ?

*Apologies for any english mistake as it is not my native language.*

*Don't hesitate to ask more info on my problem if I wasn't clear enough and thanks for the help !*

Comment: Try to change the <TargetFramework> element (which is created when you create a new .NET Standard class library project) to <TargetFrameworks> and providing a list of semicolon separated targets:

<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net45;net40</TargetFrameworks>....If your REST Server is class library, then create it using .NET standard....NET Standard libraries can be compatible with full .NET framework applications as well as .NET Core

Comment: .NET Framework and .NET Core are not the same framework and they don't interoperate, unless the assemblies involved have been *made* interoperable by targeting .NET Standard. And that's what you should do -- if both projects target .NET Standard, all assemblies can be loaded interchangeably. In this case, your .NET Core server would actually run on .NET Framework, as that's what the hosting application uses (or the other way around, depending on how you've set things up).

Comment: Well I tried to change my REST server to .Net Standard 2.0, but as I am using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0, It gives this error : Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0.0 is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0.0 supports: netcoreapp 2.0 (.NETCore,Version=v2.0)

Comment: Why the hell would you want do such a thing? Just use ASP.NET Core (Webstack!!) on .NET Framework (Runtime). ASP.NET Core **DO NOT REQUIRE** .NET Core and can run on **BOTH** runtimes